# Switch Earpiece to Speaker and Speaker to Earpiece ( UWP )

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-route

i want to know how to switch from earpiece to speaker and speaker to earpiece on button click. If any one sample project for this please share a link to help me to understand full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this solution its fully worked with media even if Earpiece or Headset is connected in UWP

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50d21bc-61d7-4058-ba6c-4da6c9b90c95/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp?forum=wpdevelop